# Caliburn.Micro fails to load view if the mouse moves too quickly?

Tags: wpf, mef, caliburn.micro

I have the weirdest error at the moment;

When my application starts there is a view asking the user which "mode" to start, which will then load the respective viewmodel. This includes some MEF voodoo with the Lazy-object.

Today I started to get freezes. I narrowed it down to "if you move the mouse too quickly and the application had just been started, it will freeze."

It will not freeze if either condition is not fulfilled: have the mouse over the button at application start and immediatly press it: no freeze. Wait for a while (4-5 seconds) then quickly move the mouse over the button and press it: no freeze. But if you do both, start the application, move the mouse quickly to the button and press it, it will freeze.

Note that the whole UI is unresponsive including the chrome from the shellviewmodel, which does not get changed in any way during this process.

I am not getting any error messages concerning this. CM log states that it happily attached the viewmodels and views, however the nested viewmodels do not appear.

Did anyone ever stumble across something similar?

The changes I had made right before I noticed this for the first time were adding different views for a listbox of different viewmodel-objects.

Comment: It looks like a threading issue, nevertheless we can never figure out. Why not listen to that button click even and see if is firing so you can trace the problem further.

Comment: The button click is firing since the viewmodel which should get loaded does indeed get loaded according to the logs, it's just the view freezing, the application is still running. Said viewmodel does fire up a few threads but I haven't changed anything on that part in quite a while. It does sound like some kind of deadlock or infinite loop on the UI thread to be honest but I have no idea what could cause it. I don't use any locking mechanism, the background threads do work and then dispatch to the UI thread.